# How to Overwrite magento app->design->adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml

I have modified

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

what is the quick process to overwrite the page?thanks

Comment: Not sure what are you asking.

Comment: You want to have a second directory next to the adminhtml/default/default directory, Something like adminhtml/default/custom/ ?

Comment: yes @SanderMangel actually i have modified above link of the page. is it necessary to overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a second templating directory to the adminhtml, for example:
`app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/`
you'll have to modify the following file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php`

add the following `__construct` method

```
public function __construct()
{
    Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('custom');
}
```

This will set the `custom` directory as primary templating directory and `default` as fallback

Of course it's better to overwrite it from your own extension. Create a class that extends the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template` class with just that constructor and add the following to your `config.xml`

```
[...]
<global>
    <blocks>
        <customextension>
            <class>Your_Customextension_Block</class>
        </customextension>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- allow for extra layer of adminhtml templating -->
                <template>Your_Customextension_Block_Mage_Adminhtml_Template</template>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
[...]
```

Comment: Create a class or module?

Comment: it's a block class that you're creating in your own extension

Comment: to extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template class i have to create one module. right? and config file i have to write your code which u have written above.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Either that or modify the core class but writing your own module or extension is prefered